# ListView with Lazy loading with downloading image

Tags: android, listview, view, lazy-loading, android-image

I have a **listview** in which images gets downloaded when I scroll so whatever I have understand till now is the element which are visible only that element's images gets downloaded. Suppose only 7 elements are visible at a time and when I Scroll previous views are **recycled** with the new once so what happens to the process which was downloading the **image** of the previous views is it also cancelled or it queues the new request of downloading images of the new Views.**I am asking about the process that queueing of process happens or the process which are not completed yet are cancelled. with process I mean downloading images in background**

Comment: @chintan-rathod I am asking that if views are recycled does the process also gets killed.

Comment: Depend upon logic. Otherwise NO.

Comment: So do you know any way where i can stop the previous process for the views which hoes out of the screen or which are recycled?

Comment: Nope.. I have not heard regarding how to get update when view get disappeared from list..

Answer (score 1):

Depends completely on how you are downloading and caching the images.

If you are using `AyncTasks` to download your images and not cancelling them as you scroll then the image will be downloaded. If you are using libraries like volley/picasso/glide to handle your images then they cancel or cache the images depending on how much of the image was downloaded.

Comment: so suppose I am using AsyncTask when i scrolled faster and lands on 60th element so do i have to wait till all images till 60th downloaded to see my image of 60th element?

Comment: Yes. How AsyncTasks behave is that internally it will only launch a limited number of threads after which all requests start going to a queue and all those requests will then be handled sequentially. To avoid this, dont start async tasks until your list has stopped scrolling.

Comment: Then how would I know that list has stopped scrolling?

Comment: By implementing an OnScrollListener

Comment: Yupp I'll implement your suggested method and if it solves I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use **Glide** or **Picasso** or **UIL** for Lazy loading of images. Instead of downloading you can get the bitmap and save them as per your need.

Comment: Yeah I'll Surely try these libraries. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It was better that put your code here , but I think if you download image asynchronously, your problem is solved. you can download image in back ground by using "dispatch_async()" method.